# Paint Not Drawing Rectangle As Expected

Tags: java, swing

This is my code and i want to draw rectangles of equal sizes but it is not drawing rectangle as i am  expecting

```
   @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        int x = 40 , y = 40 , xx=240,yy=240;
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        for(int i = 0 ;  i < 2 ;  i++){
            System.out.println("X:"+x+" Y:"+y+" XX:"+xx+" YY:"+yy);
            g.drawRect(x, y, xx, yy);
            x = (xx + 100);
            xx = x+200;
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: `i want to draw rectangles of equal sizes` - well you keep changing the width, so the size will keep changing. Custom painting should be done by overriding `paintComponent(...)` not paint(...). You need to invoke `super.paintCompnent(..)` at the start of the method to clear the background of the panel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: distance remains constant so rectangle should be of same size

Comment: `distance remains constant so rectangle should be of same size ` - that is NOT how the drawRect(...) method works. Read the API for a description of how the parameters are used.

Comment: Thanks Man not reading documentation always in lose .Thanks man